# Javascript D3 graph sorting the graph and axes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

Please excuse me as I am new to using D3 graphs. I seem to be having the problem of the graph appearing in a very weird/sideways way even after sorting. I am trying to display a graph showing an increasing trend between two values. The values from an array look something like this: `[[200, 4.232660756790275], [300, 5.206851570440669], [400, 4.459431618637297]]` where the first value is represented on the Y-axis and the second in the X-axis. Below is the code. Am I doing something wrong? Please advise, thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
    font: 12px Arial;
}

text.shadow {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    stroke-opacity: 0.7;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path {
          stroke-width: 0;
}

.area {
    fill: lightsteelblue;
      stroke-width: 0;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 35, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
 var arrData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("graphArray"));

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.idd); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.timing); });

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.idd); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.timing); });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var data = arrData.map(function(d) {
    return {

        idd: d[1],
        timing: d[0]

    };

});

console.log(data);

// function for the x grid lines
function make_x_axis() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(5)
}

// function for the y grid lines
function make_y_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
}

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.idd; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.timing; })]);

    // Add the filled area
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", area);

    // Draw the x Grid lines
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(make_x_axis()
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

    // Draw the y Grid lines
    svg.append("g")            
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .call(make_y_axis()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    // Add the text label for the X axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
                             (height+margin.bottom) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Index of Difficulty");

    // Add the white background to the y axis label for legibility
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("x", margin.top - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("class", "shadow")
        .text("Price ($)");

    // Add the text label for the Y axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("x", margin.top - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Time (ms)");

    // Add the title
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width / 2))     
        .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "16px")
        .style("text-decoration", "underline")
        .text("Fitts' Law");


</script>
</body>
```

And what the graph looks like after passing in the data from an array: 
Also, I was wondering how do i change  text for X-axis, as it appears not within the range of values that is retrieved.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont understand why you have defined the x axis as time scale.

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
```

Just by reading the variable it seems it is some id

So should have been

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
```

Next the graph is correct the data is in this order

```
 [[200, 4.232660756790275], [300, 5.206851570440669], [400, 4.459431618637297]];
```

so first it goes to 4.3 then to 5.2 and then back to 4.4, that is the reason why its coming like the image shown in the question.

I would recommend you to sort the data like below so that the order now is 4.23 then 4.45 then 5.20 ...

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.idd - b.idd;
});
```

This will make the graph as the way you want it :)

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/xwnws1wb/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you!! I understand now! Thank you so much!!